# Does python's xml.etree.ElementTree support DTD?

Tags: python, xml, dtd, elementtree

Does xml.etree.ElementTree support DTD?

if it supports it, can I force ElementTree check a XML file against a dtd file, even if the XML file already has one. (internal or external).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure about `xml.etree`, but `lxml` supports DTD validation:
http://lxml.de/validation.html