# How to Validate the XML with DTD using Python xml.etree.ElementTree Library

Tags: python-3.x, elementtree, dtd

I'm using python 3.7 and xml.etree.ElementTree library to parse the XML data as it is very easy to parse the maintain the XML file. 
Now, I need to add DTD to my XML file in order to maintain it to proper structure. 
I don't want to use some other library to achieve this. How to use DTD validation in Python's ElementTree ?

Comment: You have to use some other library. Validation against a DTD is not supported by ElementTree. Instead you can use lxml. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/5396192/407651

Comment: Thanks mzjn... Whether we will able to use lxml to validate the entire xml is valid or not in a single check ?

Comment: Yes, you can validate "in a single check". The documentation is here: https://lxml.de/validation.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does python's xml.etree.ElementTree support DTD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5396135/does-pythons-xml-etree-elementtree-support-dtd)